# Unhandled Exception in Android

Tags: android, exception, unhandled

Ok guys so i'm a newbie at Android. I am developing a login page that signsup users to a backend server. The backend service that i am using is Parse. So when i include some code to write data in the onclick method i get an error showing that there is an unhandled exception.

Here is the xml file for the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/acchead"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Create a FFOD account"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fnameffod"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Last Name"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lnameffod"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/uname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/userffod"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/userffod"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userffod"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/emailffod"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emailffod"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailffod"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/passffod"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/passffod"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passffod"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:password="true" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Btwitter1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passffod"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:src="@drawable/twitter_icon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Bfacebook1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Btwitter1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Bcreate"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon2" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bcreate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passffod"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Create Account" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fbtwitt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Bcreate"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Use FACEBOOK or TWITTER account? Touch any one!"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fnameffod"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fnameffod"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pass"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="First Name"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The .java file for the above xml is as follows:

```
package com.ffod.bingo;


import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AccountCreate extends Activity {

    String username, pass, email, firstname, lastname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        Parse.initialize(this, "my app key", "my app key");

        Button register_user; 
        EditText user_name, password, e_mail, f_name, l_name;
        user_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userffod);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passffod);
        e_mail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailffod);
        f_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fnameffod);
        l_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lnameffod);

        username = user_name.getText().toString();
        pass = password.getText().toString();
        email = e_mail.getText().toString();
        firstname = f_name.getText().toString();
        lastname = l_name.getText().toString();

        register_user = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bcreate);
        register_user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(username);
                user.setPassword(pass);
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.put("First Name", firstname);
                user.put("Last Name", lastname);
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            // Hooray! Let them use the application now.
                        } else {
                            // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                            // to figure out what went wrong
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });     
    }

}
```

Please note that i have just changed the actual values in the parse.initialize to simply appkeys.

Here is the log cat o/p:

```
>02-07 10:22:17.242: D/com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver(284): received >android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
>02-07 10:22:33.101: W/KeyCharacterMap(284): No keyboard for id 0
>02-07 10:22:33.101: W/KeyCharacterMap(284): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
>02-07 10:22:55.262: W/dalvikvm(284): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Username cannot be missing or blank
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at com.parse.ParseUser.signUp(ParseUser.java:232)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at com.parse.ParseUser$1.run(ParseUser.java:273)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at com.parse.ParseUser$1.run(ParseUser.java:1)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at com.parse.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:39)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at com.parse.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:1)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     ... 4 more
>02-07 10:23:06.851: I/Process(284): Sending signal. PID: 284 SIG: 9
```

This is a very urgent requirement. I would appreciate all the help that i could get. Thank you!

Comment: your ParseUser.signup() is throwing error: IllegalArgumentException, please check there or paste code of ParseUser.signup.

Comment: `>02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Username cannot be missing or blank` : This line says what it exactly is. Please double click on `02-07 10:22:55.335: E/AndroidRuntime(284):     at com.parse.ParseUser.signUp(ParseUser.java:232)
`  line in your logcat.

Comment: Check the value of userName that is being passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be because of this line,

```
username = user_name.getText().toString();
```

I think you might not be holding any value in your EditText which might return empty value which leads to this problem.

or since this is an EditText instead of `user_name.getText().toString();` I would suggest you to use  `user_name.getEditableText().toString();`.

The problem is since the value is empty here it is leading to some exception in your other class.

Comment: Andro Selva: Using getEditableText() does not seem to help.

Comment: r u getting some value for user name or is it empty?

Comment: @jitendrasharma : The signup is a function given by the parse service.

Comment: The LogCat is still very similar. I see an unhandled thread exception at the beginning of the logcat. Why is that being caused?

Comment: @JitendraSharma : I'm using parse. Check out www.parse.com

Comment: Andro Selva : The Datatypes are all right aren't they? Do i have any sort of datatype mismatch?